# Querying Parse.com using PHP SDK

Tags: php, parse-platform

I am trying to query Parse.com using the new PHP SDK. I have installed everything necessary. I am having a problem querying though.

link:[https://www.parse.com/docs/php_guide#queries]

I have tried using this:

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 use Parse\ParseClient;
 use Parse\ParseObject;

 ParseClient::initialize('secret1','secret2', 'secret3');


 $query = new ParseQuery("TableName");
 $query->equalTo("email", "email@me.com");
 $results = $query->find();
 echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!!

---

SOLVED using William George's help! Here is my updated code:

```
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';

 use Parse\ParseClient;
 use Parse\ParseObject;
 use Parse\ParseQuery;

 ParseClient::initialize('secret1','secret2', 'secret3');

 try{
 $query = new ParseQuery("TableName");
 $query->equalTo("email", "email@me.com");
 $results = $query->find();
 echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.";
 } catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: A blank screen on my php webpage when I added $query = new ParseQuery("TableName");
 $query->equalTo("email", "email@me.com");
 $results = $query->find();
 echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.");

Comment: If its not echoing anything then it must be crashing out somewhere. Are you running you web server locally, do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: local webserver, do you think I am just missing a 'use' statement or something because it only crashes when I try to use a query?

Comment: Check your Apache error log.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly you have a syntax error:

```
echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.");
```

Should be

```
echo "Successfully retrieved " . count($results) . " scores.";
```

Secondly you do not include `ParseQuery`

```
use Parse\ParseQuery;
```

Also, the new PHP Parse framework throws exceptions all over the place.

Wrap your code in a try catch.

```
try {
   //parse code
} catch (\Exception $e){
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

What does the output say now?

Comment: OUTPUT: Successfully retrieved 1 scores.  :) Thank you so much for catching that extra ')' and telling me to use ParseQuery. You really helped me out. Thanks!